# How To Convert the sql result set data into an XML format using PHp

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

```
<?php 
include 'dbcon.php';

$sql    ="select * from users";
$result = $adb->query($sql);

while ($row=$adb->fetch_array($result))
{
}
```

I want to store the result set in the XML format using PHP.

Comment: `<? php `!!! Remove space  between `<?` and `php`.

Comment: You should only use PHP here to call a commandline tool [*mysqldump*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) - If you insist to do that with PHP, please use the search, I know this has been answered before with code-examples.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your user table has 2 fields - fname and lname. This is the basic way to create a xml file from ur db query.

```
<?php 
include 'dbcon.php';
$sql="select * from users";
$result = $adb->query($sql);
 $xml .= "<users>";
while($row=$adb->fetch_array($result))
{
    $xml .= "<fname>".$row['fname']."</fname>"; 
    $xml .= "<lname>".$row['lname']."</lname>";
}
$xml .= "</users>";

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->asXML("test.xml");
?>
```